# using merge in strong params, NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im doing some testing on my app.

I have a form that accepts a city(autocompleted by city name), and some dates.

Because I have a autocomplete feature, I have to get the city_id by looking up the city by its display name.

```
def trip_params
    params.require(:trip).permit(:start_date, :end_date).merge(:city_id => City.find_by_display(params[:trip][:city_id]).id)
end
```

The problem is if the user sumbits the form without a city. I get an error:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Because there was no record found. Whats a better way to structure this so that I can redirect back to 'new' if no city is entered?

create method just in case its helpful.

```
def create
    @trip = current_user.trips.build(trip_params)
    if @trip.save
        flash[:success] = "Trip to #{@trip.city.name} added."
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash.now[:error] = @trip.errors.full_messages
        render 'new'    
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
    if params[:trip][:city_id].blank?
        flash[:error] = "some warning about the city"
        render new
    else
        @trip = current_user.trips.build(trip_params)
        if @trip.save
            flash[:success] = "Trip to #{@trip.city.name} added."
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            flash.now[:error] = @trip.errors.full_messages
            render 'new'    
        end
    end
end
```

or

```
def trip_params
    if !params[:trip][:city_id].blank?
        params.require(:trip).permit(:start_date, :end_date).merge(:city_id => City.find_by_display(params[:trip][:city_id]).id)
    end
end
```